# Custom @Id class for Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring-data-redis

I am trying to convert / serialize the @Id field (which is not a string) of the model class but keep getting this error. The custom ID class just concatenates two values with a colon, e.g. `aaaa:2345`.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [MyIdClass] to type [byte[]]
```

This is my model class.

```
@RedisHash("alert")
public class MyClass implements Serializable
{
    public static class MyIdClass
    {
        public String userId;
        public Long sessionExpiry;

        public MyIdClass()
        {
        }

        public MyIdClass(String id, Long ex)
        {
            userId = id;
            sessionExpiry = ex;
        }
    }

    public static class MyIdClassSerializer implements RedisSerializer<MyIdClass>
    {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(@Nullable MyIdClass uid) throws SerializationException
        {
            return String.format("%s:%d", uid.userId, uid.sessionExpiry).getBytes();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public MyIdClass deserialize(@Nullable byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException
        {
            String[] t = new String(bytes).split(":");
            return new MyIdClass(t[0], Long.parseLong(t[1]));
        }
    }

    @Component
    @ReadingConverter
    public static class MyIdClassReader implements Converter<byte[], MyIdClass>
    {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public MyIdClass convert(byte[] source)
        {
            String[] t = new String(source).split(":");
            return new MyIdClass(t[0], Long.parseLong(t[1]));
        }
    }

    @Component
    @WritingConverter
    public static class MyIdClassWriter implements Converter<MyIdClass, byte[]>
    {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public byte[] convert(MyIdClass uid)
        {
            return String.format("%s:%d", uid.userId, uid.sessionExpiry).getBytes();
        }
    }

    /**
     * User ID
     * Key := 'alert:' userId ':' sessionExpiry
     */
    @Id
    public MyIdClass id;

    public String value;
}
```

Here's how I'm configuring the RedisTemplate.

```
@Bean("redisTemplateActivityAlert")
public RedisTemplate<ActivityAlert.UserIdExpiry, ActivityAlert> redisTemplateActivityAlert()
{
    RedisTemplate<ActivityAlert.UserIdExpiry, ActivityAlert> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(new ActivityAlert.UserIdExpirySerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new ActivityAlert.UserIdExpirySerializer());
    return template;
}
```

I've read other posts about configuring `ConversionService` or `TypeConverter` but haven't gone far with them.

Answer (score 1):

add this Bean to your RedisConfiguration :

```
    @Bean
    public RedisCustomConversions redisCustomConversions(MyIdClassReader  myIdClassReader , MyIdClassWriter  myIdClassWriter ) {
        return new RedisCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(myIdClassWriter,myIdClassReader)); 
    }
```